# Extract a purchase order # from a string in C# and put it in another string

Tags: c#, string

I have data stored in strings that I need to extract and turn into another string.  My string data looks like this:

Widget  PO NO. 1234
Body PO NO. 123456
Wing    PO NO. 12345-2
Nut  PO NO. 1-234-56-7

"PO NO." will always be the same, so I just want to extract the data after the trailing space in "NO. ", and turn it into another string so I can have the numeric data (i.e the purchase order #).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        const string refString = "PO NO.";
        string aLine = "Widget PO NO. 1234";

        string orderNumb = aLine.Substring(aLine.LastIndexOf(refString) + refString.Length).Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using your actual string representations you have a space after each textual portion...so to provide yet another route...

```
String rawPO = "Body PO NO. 123456";
String trimmedPO = rawPO.Remove(0, rawPO.LastIndexOf(" ")).Trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regular Expressions:

```
       Match m = Regex.Match(str, @"PO NO\. (?<PO>\d+)$");
       string poNumber = m.Groups["PO"].Value;
```

Comment: Regex really cost too much. Not needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Try [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
strOrder = "Widget PO NO. 1234";
arSplit = strOrder.Split(" PO NO. ");
```

This creates an array `arsplit[]` with everything before PO NO. in `arSplit[0]` and everything after in `arsplit[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Regular Expression to extract the parts you need.  This regular expression will return grouped results:

```
[.\W]*PO NO\.\W*([\d-]*)
```

Here's some demo code (C#):

```
string[] strings = new string[] {"Widget PO NO. 1234",
                            "Body PO NO. 123456",
                            "Wing PO NO. 12345-2",
                            "Nut PO NO. 1-234-56-7"};
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[.\W]*PO NO\.\W*([\d-]*)");
Match match;

foreach (string s in strings)
{
    match = regex.Match(s);
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

Comment: Regex really cost too much. Not needed here.

Answer (score 0):

```
string order = orders.Split(" ")[3];
```

Comment: Though this would depend on the the type name always being one word, so I'd be careful with this (though if you amend it to not have a hardcoded `3` and instead look up how many parts there are it would be ok I suppose).

Comment: @JYL: I'm just working with the data presented. Just use [array.Count - 1] if additional spaces are possible.